# Rotate UIView while dragging

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rotation, uigesturerecognizer

Using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, I'm allowing the user to drag a `UIView`.  What I now want to accomplish is getting the view to adjust its rotation around a specified point DURING dragging.

Examples of this can be found in the Tinder App (when dragging a portrait the images rotate slightly) or in the Path App (when dragging a friends popup up or down it rotates to the side grabbed on).

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I have very little experience working with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, but I assume that it won't affect the answer.

Nevertheless one solution could be to create a timer and make it run while the `UIView` is being dragged, the timer action would then make sure to update the rotation of the `UIView` properly and as often as possible.

Another solution could be to subclass `UIView` and overwrite the drag-function (I do not know what it is called) and simply make it self adjust its rotation if any pivot point is given.

Answer (score 0):

Do the rotation in the following method

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat angle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **CATransform3D**

Add

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(d) (d * M_PI / 180)
```

in .pch file

```
CATransform3D myTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
myTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
myTransform = CATransform3DRotate(myTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
myView.layer.transform = myTransform;
```

you can go on changing the angle here DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) Hope this will help you